# email address missing from permissions list using google drive api

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-drive-api

I am using google drive to give drive folder permissions. I am able to create permission for the shared drive using google drive API but when I get the list i don't get permission email address

```
const drive = google.drive({ version: 'v3', auth: oauth2Client });
await drive.permissions.create({
          fileId: franchiseFolderId,
          supportsAllDrives: true,
          requestBody: {
            type: 'user',
            role: 'writer',
            emailAddress: userEmail,
          },
        });
const permissions = await drive.permissions.list({
          fileId: folderId,
          supportsAllDrives: true,
        });
console.log('permissions', permissions.data.permissions);
```

from above permissions console i only get this information

```
[{
id: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
type: 'user',
kind: 'drive#permission',
role: 'writer'
  }]
```

email address is there in typescript type file but not in the response.
i am using google oauth 2 for authorization and i have one scope added when generating tokens

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the case of "Permissions: list" of Drive API v3, it seems that the email address is not returned as the default value. So, in your showing script, how about using `fields` property as follows?

#### From:

```
const permissions = await drive.permissions.list({
          fileId: folderId,
          supportsAllDrives: true,
        });
```

#### To:

```
const permissions = await drive.permissions.list({
          fileId: folderId,
          supportsAllDrives: true,
          fields: "*", // <--- Added
        });
```

#### Note:

- If you want to retrieve only permission IDs and email addresses, you can also use the value of `fields` as follows.

  ```
    fields: "permissions(id,emailAddress),nextPageToken",
  ```

#### Reference:

- [Permissions: list of Drive API v3](Permissions: list)