# Test service account can write a google sheets spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am wondering if there is an api I can use to test if a service account has write access to a google spreadsheet, I know you can do that with other APIs using the testIamPermissions permission, but there does not seem to be an equivalent for sheets api.

Currently I am actually testing write access by trying to write a developer metadata property, which is not ideal because it generates a version of the spreadsheet :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Google Sheet Permission List:

I understand that you are looking to check if a service account has access to your spreadsheet without using a write method that generates a version.

Due to the nature of the service account needed to be added on permission's list you can use Google Drive Permissions API. Here on this [link](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/permissions#list). Using that should generate a list of permitted accounts and with a little play around the fields you can get the exact emails.

### Screenshot Reference of the Permission's API:

On the screenshot you can see my service account listed and other email for testing purposes.

### Screenshot of the JSON Response:

[image]

### Screenshot of Current Permissions:

[image]

### Screenshot revealing the file emailAddress fields:

[image]

==================================

## References:

[Google Drive API Permissions](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/permissions#list)

Comment: Hi! Jason. Please don't hesitate to comment if you have further questions.  Feel free to accept my answer (by clicking the accept button on the left) so that other members in the community (who may have the same concerns as you) may know that their problem can also be solved with this answer

Comment: Hi, I am only just starting to look at this, it looks like it should solve my issue, the only wrinkle will be that I suspect my service account needs to have access to the google drive api to use it, this makes it a little more complicated to setup for my customers, but I can't really see another way around it.

Comment: @Jason Pell I understand, depending on your use cases that might be a wrinkle, there is only limited I can share without a good oversight over your project. But good to hear that you are on the right part on this one.  Feel free to accept my answer (by clicking the accept button on the left) so that other members in the community (who may have the same concerns as you) may know that their problem can also be solved with this answer

Comment: Ok, so I managed to get this working, but the email was not being returned, stackoverflow saved me again, I had to set the fields field to get the email address returned.  For whatever reason the id of my service account returned in the permissions list is not the client id, anyway I found a hint for this from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74813083/email-address-missing-from-permissions-list-using-google-drive-api

Comment: Good for you I really hope that the community have been a great help for you to move forward to your project.